# Are there any writings and resources regarding Ashardalon and his presence in Firestorm Peak?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms

I recently got the [Wrath of Ashardalon](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/66356/dungeons-dragons-wrath-ashardalon-board-game) board game and want to extend my experience by reading more about the setting. However, I couldn't find any by googling. I only found the wiki entry for [Ashardalon](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ashardalon) and found it to be lacking.

I'm also planning to take inspiration from the reading materials on how I will be painting the board game's 41 miniatures. Mostly I'm interested in the environment -- What kind of dungeon lies beneath Firestorm Peak? Would Ashardalon be sitting atop a pile of gold a-la Smaug? What treasures would he keep? What does his lair look like?

Comment: I can't access EN World from work, but they have an article about [Ashardalon Lore](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj6jr_43Y_kAhUGKqwKHc5KCNgQFjACegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.enworld.org%2Fthreads%2Fwho-is-ashardalon.190547%2F&usg=AOvVaw1NkhFIyh5jlQ9SnaCuO_tA) that may be useful.

Comment: @Raj [Cross posting is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). It could be migrated if deemed appropriate, though.  I guess it's a matter of if the OP is looking for novels about Ashardalon or 3rd edition D&D or just any info, though the painting schemes mention implies more RPG/Monster Manual info.  Perhaps the OP will clarify?

Comment: @eshier Sorry, I'm not sure I understood you. Are you suggesting I migrate the question to a different StackExchange site? Generally, I am looking for lore material for Ashardalon, so novels and related literature, but I would consider RPG/Monster Manual lore information to be relevant as well, if that makes sense? Thank you!

Comment: @brain56 A user had suggested that your question be posted on the RPG stack in addition to this post.  I was explaining that was not allowed.  He realized his mistake and deleted the comment.  It is a perfectly fine question for this site, but as you can see in my answer probably MORE appropriate on the RPG.  If it were me, I'd leave it here.  However, if you want more information, you might ask an additional question on the RPG stack to clarify.  I would definitely mention this question and what more info you want if you do that, though.  Questions on _Wrath_ could go to the board game stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ashardalon, the great red dragon, started as a background character and antagonist in the last chapter of an 8-module adventure series for Dungeons & Dragons 3e in 2000-2002.  The first, last (where the dragon actually appears), and one other were written by [Bruce Cordell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Cordell).  There do not seem to be any novels dealing with this character, so only the background information from the 8 modules would apply.  The board game is apparently set after the adventure path.

Cordell is also the author of the Dungeons & Dragons 2e adventure [*The Gates of Firestorm Peak*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gates_of_Firestorm_Peak) which is [regarded very highly](https://www.librarything.com/bookaward/Dungeon+magazine%27s+%22The+30+Greatest+D%2526D+Adventures+of+All+Time%22).  The module should give you a very good picture of the Firestorm Peak.  There is no mention of Ashardalon in that adventure, though.

[One of your links in the question](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ashardalon) contained this history/explanation taken from *The Draconomicon*:

> After suffering a mortal wound, Ashardalon attempted to extend his life by binding a balor called Ammet to his chest in order to function as a second heart. However, his injuries were too extensive for the balor's power to keep Ashardalon alive. He then moved to a domain in the Astral Plane known as the Bastion of Unborn Souls and established his lair there. He was kept alive thanks to the timeless nature of the Astral Plane and the unusual flow of energy that permeated the Bastion.

This wordpress site, [Scholoars and Serpents](https://scholarsandserpents.wordpress.com/), has an extensive summary of the background information and details from the modules that puts that very brief summary into context.  Here is the timeline proposed there as a start:

> Ashardalon ravages the world
>
> His cult worships him as a god
>
> Gulthias [cult member] makes Nightfang Spire his temple
>
> An Elvish dragon cult builds the Sunless Citadel
>
> Ashardalon destroys the druids
>
> Dydd the Wise [leader of the druids] creates a new people
>
> Dydd cuts Ashardalon’s heart from his chest
>
> Ashardalon escapes to the Abyss
>
> Gulthias brings the heart to Nightfang Spire
>
> The Sunless Citadel is destroyed
>
> Gulthias becomes a vampire
>
> Gulthias travels to the Sunless Citadel
>
> Gulthias is staked to the ground in the Twilight Grove
>
> Belak the Outcast finds the Citadel
>
> Belak helps the Gulthias Tree create the Twig Blights and lures adventurers into the Grove
>
> A party of adventures release Gulthias by destroying the tree
>
> Gulthias returns to Nightfang Spire. Centuries go by
>
> Adventurers kill Gulthias
>
> At some point prior Ashardalon infuses Ammet [a balor] into his chest
>
> Ashardalon uses Desayeus’ totem to enter the Bastion
>
> The Demogorgon wants to extract the balor from Ashardalon
>
> The Demogorgon sends The Cathazar to search for Dydd’s ancestor
>
> The Cathazar uses Dyson to open a demonic portal
>
> Dyson is defeated
>
> The soul sickness appears
>
> The soul sickness troubles the gods
>
> Dydd’s ancestor enters the positive plane and kills Ashardalon and the balor.
>
> Ashardalon becomes a vestige

It also contains this quote from *Dragon* #365:

> Few can ignore the legacy of the mighty red dragon Ashardalon. Ancient even by the standards of dragonkind, he was a force for evil in the world—his ferocity and greed was unmatched by any of his kin. Even when the great druid Dydd put down the beast, ending his reign of terror, Ashardalon rose from the ashes of his grave once more, bolstered by his wickedness and by fell pacts made with dread abominations. Although we can rest easy in the knowledge that the menace posed by this beast is no more (or so we hope), Ashardalon remains a  cause of wonder and speculation.

---

The default setting for Dungeons & Dragons 3e is [Greyhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhawk#Third_edition) so the original modules are set there.  They usually left setting rather vague, though, so it could take place anywhere.  The first two modules were recently (2017) [reprinted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Yawning_Portal) and set in Forgotten Realms.

---

If you are looking for painting advice, [this BoardGameGeek list](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/66184/dd-monster-manual-wrath-ashardalon-edition) has all the monsters and includes examples from the D&D miniatures line to represent them--*i.e.* a painted example.  Likewise, any entry in an appropriate Dungeons & Dragons Monster Manual or just looking online for each monster should give you ideas.

Comment: Awesome! This is really helpful! Thank you!